# Laravel Firebase authentication

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

wonder if it possible to authenticate users to Firebase from Laravel?

I am using laravel as a rest API behind my webapp and ios app. What I want to do is once user logs into my api I want to log them into firebase as well since my chat/notifications will depend on firebase.

I have already used this lib in order to sync my models to firebase: https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The library `laravel-firebase-sync` is only meant to sync your laravel collections with firebase, in order to use laravel's authentication you'd need to write your own authentication method that matched.

Firebase authentication uses a firebase specific authentication. You'd need to replicate or implement 
[Authentication with Firebase in JavaScript Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) or whatever measure necessary with your webapp/ios app.